# Intergrating firebase real time database to android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

App doesn't receive data from firebase console.

I have set up INTERNET permission in the manifest file.
I have also have one listview in my layout file.
Firebase assistant also shows my app is connected to Firebase,dependencies set up correctly

Here's my java class:

```
public class Todaytips extends Activity implements ValueEventListener {
    DatabaseReference dref;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.todaytips);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list);
        dref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
             String value= dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                list.add(value);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                String value= dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                list.remove(value);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_one, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Itamar Green

Answer (score 0):

This way works for me, 1st declare DatabaseReference outside your onCreate method;

```
DatabaseReference dbRef =     FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference
```

Then, create a reference name to your db with their respective TextView;

```
DatabaseReference tView = dbRef.child("AValueNameThatYouGiveInConsole");
```

Declare a TextView variable,

```
TextView text1; (this can go on in one line)
```

Inside onCreate,

```
text1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.YourTextViewID's)
```

3rd step, outside onCreate method, create a new method called onStart.

```
@Override
protected void onStart(){
super.onStart();

tView.addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener() {

@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
String x = snapshot.getValue(String.class); text1.setText(x); }
```

//Let onCancelled method as it is

Comment: Where did you stuck at? Letme suggest some ways.

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 0):

I had different project IDs because my android studio and firebase were logged in 
on different google accounts.